# Using a single port for bittorrent-tracker server in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, bittorrent

I am trying to build/deploy a tracker server for use with P2P applications using the below code. It works fine locally, but when I deploy it to Heroku, the port bindings fail because only one port is allowed.

```
    // Create a web sockets signaling server
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();

    //Allow all requests from all domains & localhost
    app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
        next();
    });

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

    let lookup = {}

    const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
    const port = process.env.PORT;

    var Server = require('bittorrent-tracker').Server

    var server = new Server({
        udp: false, // enable udp server? [default=true]
        http: true, // enable http server? [default=true]
        ws: true, // enable websocket server? [default=true]
        stats: true, // enable web-based statistics? [default=true]
    })

    server.on('error', function (err) {
        // fatal server error!
        console.log(err.message)
    })

    server.on('warning', function (err) {
        // client sent bad data. probably not a problem, just a buggy client.
        console.log(err.message)
    })

    server.on('listening', function () {
        // fired when all requested servers are listening
        console.log('Signal server http port:' + server.http.address().port)
        console.log('Signal server ws port:' + server.ws.address().port)
    })

    // start tracker server listening! Use 0 to listen on a random free port.
    server.listen(port, hostname, 'listening')

    // listen for individual tracker messages from peers:
    server.on('start', function (addr) {
        console.log('got start message from ' + addr)
        Object.keys(server.torrents).forEach(hash => {
            lookup[server.torrents[hash].infoHash] = server.torrents[hash].peers.length
            console.log("peers: " + server.torrents[hash].peers.length)
        })
    })

    server.on('complete', function (addr) {})
    server.on('stop', function (addr) {})

    app.get('/peers', function(req, res) {
        res.send(lookup);
    })

    app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
        console.log('Express server port: ' + this.address().port); //Listening on port #
    })
```

If I use `process.env.PORT` for both `server` and `app`, I get the following, which is expected since Heroku only allows 1 listen port:

```
2021-02-13T05:35:31.016101+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-13T05:35:30.885170+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server port: 9898
2021-02-13T05:35:30.885204+00:00 app[web.1]: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:9898
2021-02-13T05:35:30.885205+00:00 app[web.1]: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:9898
```

If I hard code the port for either `server` or `app`, the application launches fine, but the signaling server doesn't work. No substantial logging is generated.

```
2021-02-13T05:38:21.141806+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-13T05:38:20.998054+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server port: 25702
2021-02-13T05:38:20.998550+00:00 app[web.1]: Signal server http port:31415
2021-02-13T05:38:20.998683+00:00 app[web.1]: Signal server ws port:31415
```

Is it possible that the `bittorrent-tracker` server and `express` server can use the same port? For instance, could I get and return the list of peers within this block of code without the need for `express` at all?

```
    server.on('start', function (addr) {
        console.log('got start message from ' + addr)
        // Could I do something here to eliminate the need for Express?
        Object.keys(server.torrents).forEach(hash => {
            lookup[server.torrents[hash].infoHash] = server.torrents[hash].peers.length
            console.log("peers: " + server.torrents[hash].peers.length)
        })
    })
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/webtorrent/bittorrent-tracker) states:

> The http server will handle requests for the following paths:
> /announce, /scrape. Requests for other paths will not be handled.

But perhaps there is some way I can shim in the requests that `express` is handling?

Comment: Well - I'll be darned... I just realized that I don't need express at all! Express in the code example in my question is completely unnecessary. I will post an answer just in case someone would like to see the complete working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not long after asking this question, it occurred to me that I might not need `express` at all. It turns out that was correct.

For anyone wanting a Heroku-ready bittorrent-tracker, here is the updated code:

```
// Create a web sockets signaling server
let lookup = {}

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = process.env.PORT;


var Server = require('bittorrent-tracker').Server

var server = new Server({
    udp: false, // enable udp server? [default=true]
    http: true, // enable http server? [default=true]
    ws: true, // enable websocket server? [default=true]
    stats: true, // enable web-based statistics? [default=true]
})

server.on('error', function (err) {
    // fatal server error!
    console.log(err.message)
})

server.on('warning', function (err) {
    // client sent bad data. probably not a problem, just a buggy client.
    console.log(err.message)
})

server.on('listening', function () {
    // fired when all requested servers are listening
    console.log('Signal server http port:' + server.http.address().port)
    console.log('Signal server ws port:' + server.ws.address().port)
})

// start tracker server listening! Use 0 to listen on a random free port.
server.listen(port, hostname, 'listening')

// listen for individual tracker messages from peers:
server.on('start', function (addr) {
    console.log('got start message from ' + addr)
    Object.keys(server.torrents).forEach(hash => {
        lookup[server.torrents[hash].infoHash] = server.torrents[hash].peers.length
        console.log("peers: " + server.torrents[hash].peers.length)
    })
})

server.on('complete', function (addr) {})
server.on('stop', function (addr) {})
```